# AngularJs + JWT + WCF or WebAPI

Tags: angularjs, wcf, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have a small angular js application where I am using angular js, typescript & html 5 for my UI. I have currently wired up the UI to get data via Restful WCF service (c#). All here works fine. Now I am looking to implement security/authentication in my application where I would like to have login/logout/register page. I have read about JWT and looks like a good one. Is this the standard nowdays of using JWT or if there are others options available.

If JWT is a good option for my site (pubic website), could anyone provide inputs where I can start with. I could not find much helpful basic posts that would guide how to create a simple form in angular and hit wcf/web api sercvice.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: anyone else with their inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a good experience with the open-source `IdentityServer3` project. They support JWT authentication from client to Web API. I myself have used it both as an authentication server providing tokens and as a middle-ware in the Web API for authorizing different controllers.

Here's a link to their [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/).